# Upvoted answer deleted due to removed user

Tags: bug

Yesterday, I posted an answer (that was upvoted) to a question that has been deleted (I assume because the user was removed).

- [world war two - Did Hitler want to prevent Soviets from Europe invasion? - History Stack Exchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/70524/38607)

> This post is hidden. It was deleted 6 hours ago by Community Bot.
>
> > - *User 55584 destroyed*

Based on the 2020 accepted answer here:

- [A question should not be deleted by the user deletion algorithm if it has upvoted answers - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312594/531408)

> So after reviewing the data, here's what I think makes sense: delete a user's questions along with them only when those questions...
>
> ...score < 0 AND
> ...are closed OR
> ...**have no answers scoring > 0**
> This change is now live.

this should not have happened, since an answer existed with 5 votes.

The question itsself had a score of 0 and was not closed.

So both conditions were **not** fulfilled to delete the original question.

Comment: Read the last comment under the meta post you linked. *If an author **is destroyed**, then all of their posts (and comments) will be **deleted unconditionally**, @TylerH. This is an option for moderators. – 
Shog9* The above options are for self-deleted users. The user whose question you answered was ***destroyed***, so all trace of the question (and answers) will be removed.

Comment: @justCal Maybe that comment should be intergrated into the answer. Including what the justification is, that the moderator should decide, that the user of the answer (made in good faith) should also be punished? Not very transparent.

Comment: There is a lot that is not transparent 'behind the curtain', and *many* users have left due to it.  Basically, however, users(the OP in this case) are destroyed typically for serious offenses. @T.E.D has destroyed the question in the feed, replacing it with a Troll marker, indicating this *may have been* a sock puppet account of our recurring troll, just stirring up crap. If a question is proposing an apologetic revision of the facts in favor of the Nazis, probably best to not answer it. We had a debate here once over if all *answers* to bad questions should actually *be downvoted* as well...

Comment: @justCal The goal (main purpose) of the answer, in this case, was to refute these claims. But this effort has now been lost.

Comment: @justCal - Yeah, we have one particular Nazi troll who likes to come home here for the holidays. Happy Hanukkah!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a certain very small set of persistent trolls that won't take a decades-long suspension for an answer, and like to try to create sock accounts to continue trolling. They are usually pretty easy to spot, and of course trying to evade a suspension with a sock account is a TOS violation, so any such sock account will be destroyed on sight.

As was mentioned in the comments there's a difference between accounts that are [deleted vs. ones that are destroyed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user). The short of it is that in addition to what deletion does, everything the user created (posts/comments) is also deleted, *and* their IP address gets blocked.<sup>*</sup>  The other types of users that get this kind of treatment are anyone who posts nothing but spam or nonsense, or does so on their first post from an unregistered account.

For the known trolls, often a SE pro mod will merge their account with the banned one, and do a whole lot more work which I believe includes *also* deleting anything (presumably including a question with answers) that the sock created. We've discussed handling this exact situation with SE pro mods and with other mods across the network many times, and account mulching (destruction) is probably the best tool we local site mods have for this situation. Either way, if you respond to them directly, you're likely howling into the void.

In general we don't like to make a big hairy deal about it when this is done, because upsetting people is exactly what a troll wants. Hurting people and shaking up anthills is how they get their jollies. So the quicker and more professionally done, the better.

I will apologize that we didn't manage to identify and mulch that account before you were tricked into responding. Usually we mulch that sock-troll's stuff quite quickly, often in less than an hour, but in this case it appears to have been up for the better part of a day.

It also really sucks that an answer the community seems to have liked (I see it at +5 right now) got caught in the process. I'm not sure this has happened before, so we don't really have a process to cover it. I mean, better to not let the troll's stuff stay up so long in the first place, but we obviously failed there, and if it happened once, its liable to happen again. Perhaps we should discuss how to handle that situation here in case it comes up again? Another meta question specifically on that perhaps?

---

<sup>* - I know this terminology is confusing. It was super confusing to **me** since they both start with "de" and mean roughly the same thing in English. So instead of "destroyed" I prefer to say "mulched".</sup>

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I have a post [with a score of 120](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke/234732#234732) that got its question deleted out from under it 10 years after I posted it. Yeah, I'm not happy about it either.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The goal should **also** be to avoid collateral damage to non participients. What effect would **Undelete** have on the original question? I wrote the answer as a debunking of such loaded statments, since in my personal experience refuting these claims using the 'voice of their master' was mostly effective in halting any further 'discussion'. The **Undelete** function could then offer a moderator a more tailored response (as a stage 2 of the mulching process).

Comment: @MarkJohnson - I saw there's an undelete vote there. Can't speak for the other mods, but if the community wants that question back, I certainly won't stand in the way. My own problem with that is that I'm strongly against the troll gaining anything whatsoever for their cheating the system with socks, and that includes having their trolling post still exist. Arguably they don't seem to need any further encouragement anyway, but I still feel like we shouldn't be providing it.

Comment: Another option, if this undelete vote fails would be to find a similar non-deleted question and merge the answer into it. That assumes there exists such a question though.

Comment: Slippery slope between allowing this question and holocaust denial/pseudo-science/conspiracy theory questions. We allow one we become a target for graffiti of all types.

Comment: @T.E.D.,justCal That vote was from me and I assume most others won't see the question at all. The question is if the answer is a worthy rebuttal of such a claim that other readers can use when encountering such things in the future (that was, and is, my main motive). Sense it is a 'Slippery slope', such a matter may best be resolved by a consensus of multiple moderators. Some *stage 2* solution is, I think, required for such border line situations.